# OpsCenter shows a datacenter as unknown even though the agents are connected

Tags: opscenter

We added a datacenter to our cluster and it is shown as "Unknown DataCenter". The dashboard reports all the agents as **connected**, and neither the agents logs nor opscenter logs show any error.

The steps we followed were the following:

- We added a datacenter using the official procedure (with vnodes enabled)
- It appeared normally in OpsCenter
- We realized we didn't want vnodes so we decomissioned all the nodes in the new datacenter
- We disabled vnodes in the config and restarted the new servers (after cleaning data/commitlog dirs)
- They are properly joined to the cluster according to nodetool status
- OpsCenter shows them as "Unknown"

We tried uninstalling/reinstalling both the agents and OpsCenter with no success. We also tried removing everything in the `OpsCenter` keyspace and removing the cluster from the UI.

Comment: What version of OpsCenter are you using?

Comment: We are using OpsCenter 5.0 on Cassandra 2.0.6

Answer (score 0):

The datacenter is now properly displayed. What seems to have been a problem is the lack of Keyspaces replicated to the new datacenter.

During our first attempt to join the datacenter to the cluster, the OpsCenter Keyspace was still using `SimpleStrategy` and was replicated to the new nodes, but we changed it to `NetworkTopologyStrategy` before the second attempt.

So when we altered our business Keyspaces to be replicated on the new datacenter, the new DC was displayed in OpsCenter right away.